# How to show Order count of logged in user across the views?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to show the order count on top of the navbar across views. I know about *Shared Views* but the problem I am having that `Auth::check()` is always false here even I am logged in. How can I make the following happen in `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider`? Is there some other way to do it or I have to rely on Session vars?

```
if(Auth::check()) {
            $orders = Order::where( [ 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'status' => 0 ] )->get();
            dd($orders);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, in the `boot` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('*', function ($view)  {
        if(Auth::check()) {
            $order_count = Order::where( [ 'user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'status' => 0 ] )->count();
            $view->with('order_count', $order_count);
        }
    });  

}
```